# Does continuity on rays imply measurability?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, reference-request

Let us define a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by defining it on all lines crossing the origin $y=tx$,  $t\in\mathbb{R}$. It is defined to be continuous on these lines. Is it known to be measurable?

Comment: Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of the circle $S^1$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=|x|$ if $x/|x|\in A$ and zero elsewhere. Could you prove that $f^{-1}[1/2,1]\simeq A\times [1/2,1]$ is not measurable?

Answer (score -1):

Let A be non-mesurable subset of $\left\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\| = 1 \right\rbrace$,

Then $B = \left\lbrace tx\in \mathbb{R}^n : x\in A ,  t\in\mathbb{R} \right\rbrace$

And now define the function f as :

$f(x) = 0$ if $x \not\in B$ and $f(x) = {\|x\|}$ if $x\in B$

then $f^{-1}(\left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace) = A$, that is non measurable

Comment: It's very confusing. $f$ is scalar? $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued? What is $f(0)$? Why is $f^{-1}(1)$ equal to $A$. But in particular: if $A$ is a non-measurable subset of $S^{n-1}$, it **is measurable** wrt. $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (it is a null-set).

Comment: Are you sure that the intersection of every non-mesurable set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $S^{n-1}$ is measurable?

Comment: According to the standard definition of Lebesgue measure that I was taught in school yes, any subset of a null-set is a (measurable) null-set. (One alternative definition of measurable set is that it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all Borel sets and all null-sets)

Comment: Oh, yes, I was using the Borel measurability... but then your comment under the question is also wrong, because it's in substance the same construction

Comment: I don't see why it's wrong.. If you can prove that a product of a non-measurable set and an interval of *positive length* is non-measurable (in the product space), then it makes sense. This proof might be a bit technical, therefore I included it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see where I did wrong, I should have not taken the inverse image of {1}, but, as you've done, [1,2]. Thanks